# Soap service in Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, soap

I'm doing my updates for my Soap service with the new version of Swift, but I don't know how to resolve these errors:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var mutableData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData.alloc()
    var currentElementName: NSString = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> ...</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"



        var urlString = "https://..."

        var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        var theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        var msgLength = String(count(soapMessage))

        theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        theRequest.addValue("urn:ResponseAction", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        connection?.start()
        if(connection == true) {
            var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
        }
    }


    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        mutableData.length = 0;
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        mutableData.appendData(data)
    }


    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)
    {
        challenge.sender.useCredential(NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust), forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
        challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        let xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: mutableData)
        xmlParser.delegate = self
        xmlParser.parse()
        xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser,
        didStartElement elementName: String,
        namespaceURI: String?,
        qualifiedName qName: String?,
        attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        currentElementName = elementName
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if currentElementName == "LoginReturn" {
            print(string)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Errors:

> /Users/informatiqueresponis/Desktop/...
>   2/SoapSwift/ViewController.swift:28:32: Cannot invoke 'count' with an
>   argument list of type '(String)'
>
> /Users/informatiqueresponis/Desktop/...
>   2/SoapSwift/ViewController.swift:66:10: Objective-C method
>   'parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:'
>   provided by method
>   'parser(*:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:)'
>   conflicts with optional requirement method
>   'parser(*:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:)' in
>   protocol 'NSXMLParserDelegate'
>
> /Users/informatiqueresponis/Desktop/...
>   2/SoapSwift/ViewController.swift:13:52: 'alloc()' is unavailable in
>   Swift: use object initializers instead
>
> /Users/informatiqueresponis/Desktop/...
>   2/SoapSwift/ViewController.swift:54:19: Value of optional type
>   'NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender?' not unwrapped; did you mean to
>   use '!' or '?'?
>
> /Users/informatiqueresponis/Desktop/...
>   2/SoapSwift/ViewController.swift:54:92: Value of optional type
>   'SecTrust?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
>
> /Users/informatiqueresponis/Desktop/...
>   2/SoapSwift/ViewController.swift:55:19: Value of optional type
>   'NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender?' not unwrapped; did you mean to
>   use '!' or '?'?

I did corrections of my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var mutableData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var currentElementName: NSString = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let soapMessage = "..."



        let urlString = "https://..."

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let msgLength = String(soapMessage.characters.count)

        theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        theRequest.addValue("urn:ResponseAction", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        let connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        connection?.start()
        if(connection == true) {
            let mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
        }
    }


    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        mutableData.length = 0;
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        mutableData.appendData(data)
    }


    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)
    {
        challenge.sender!.useCredential(NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!), forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
        challenge.sender!.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        let xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: mutableData)
        xmlParser.delegate = self
        xmlParser.parse()
        xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser,
        didEndElement elementName: String,
        namespaceURI: String?,
        qualifiedName qName: String?,
        attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        currentElementName = elementName
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if currentElementName == "LoginReturn" {
            print(string)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

But when I run my app I get nothing